# Add a result of another script into a table with awk

Tags: awk, field

I have an awk script (let's call it **my_script**) which gives output as one column, like this:

```
DD
EE
AA
CC
BB
```

I also have another table:

```
C1 123
C3 222
C5 175
C4 318
C8 299
```

I want to add it to my existing table as the last column:

```
C1 123 DD
C3 222 EE
C5 175 AA
C4 318 CC
C8 299 BB
```

I tried the following script but it didn't work:

```
awk '{print $0, $3=myscript}' file.txt
```

Comment: Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to start learning about awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste`:

```bash
my_script |
paste -d ' ' table.txt -
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I paste more than one script?

Comment: @Dr.HeinzDoofenshmirtzPhD for "pasting" the output of multiple scripts then you'll need to use bash processes substitutions, for example `paste -d ' ' <(my_script1) <(my_script2) <(my_script3)`

Comment: There are, of course, alternatives. The better response IMHO would be - ask a new question with it's own [mcve].